# How to show all content of an array in Java

Tags: java, arrays

this is my first post on this web site, so please be patience :)
I'm studying java and I'm trying to create a small program that storage in two arrays the name of player and the attendance of them. I'm using JOptionPane for the 'user interface'. I would like, when the user ask for, to show the names and the respective attendance of them. 
Here it's my code(it's not completed):

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.text.*;

public class Pelada{
    public static void main(String []args){
        String[] players = new String[10];
    int[] attendance = new int[10];
    int x = 0, z = 0, control = 0, posPlayer = 0;
    String test;

    while(control != 4){
        control = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"1- Add       new players \n 2- List \n 3- Increment attendance \n 4- Delete player \n 4- Exit", "Choose an option below", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE));
            if(control == 1){
                players[x] = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "New player: ", "Add New Player", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
                attendance[x] = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "How many matchs have he played so far? ", "Attendance", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE));
                x++;
            }   
            else if(control == 2)
                    for (int i=0; i < players.length; i++){
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Attendance = " + attendance[i], "N: " + i + "- " + players[i], JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);       
                    }
                else if(control == 3){
                        posPlayer = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Choose the player id: ", "Player Id", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE));
                        attendance[posPlayer] = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Increment ", "Attendance", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE));
                    }                   
    }

}
```

}

Comment: What exactly is your question? Your code already lists all players together with their attendance, doesn't it?

Comment: If you are using a recent enough version of Java, have a look at the for-each loop construct: `for (type x : listOfXs) { ... }` instead of manually iterating over the array and getting each element. Going with @dogbane's suggestion to make it more OO-correct will make this trivial, and greatly reduce the clutter caused by boilerplate code.

Comment: Also, just a suggestion, but do fix your indentation (and perhaps whitespacing as well). It will make the code MUCH easier to read if you indent consistently (regardless of how exactly you indent) instead of, as it is, haphazardly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of having two arrays; one for players and one for attendance, make your code more object-oriented by creating a `Player` class encapsulating the name and attendance of a player:

```
public class Player {
    private final String name;
    private final int attendance;

    public Player(String name, int attendance) {
        this.name = name;
        this.attendance = attendance;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public int getAttendance() {
        return attendance;
    }
}
```

Then create `Player` objects and store them in an `ArrayList`. Don't use an array unless you know how many players are going to be added.

```
List<Player> players = new ArrayList<Player>();

if (control == 1) {
     String name = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "New player: ", "Add New Player",
             JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
     int attendance = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,
             "How many matchs have he played so far? ", "Attendance", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE));
     Player player = new Player(name, attendance);
     players.add(player);

} else if (control == 2) {
    for (int i = 0; i < players.size(); i++) {
        Player player = players.get(i);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Attendance = " + player.getAttendance(), "N: " + i + "- " + player.getName(),
                JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
    }                
}
```

Comment: This was a great solution. It took me a while to understand though as I'm a beginner. One doubt regarding to the code where is written Player player = player.get(i); Are u creating another object from the Player class. If I'm right, why don't u need to use new? Thanks a lo

Comment: `Player player = players.get(i);` returns the player at index `i` from the `players` arraylist. It doesn't create a new object, but retrieves an existing one from the list.

Comment: so why do we need to write Player(which is a class) and not only use player = player.get(i); ?